# Rows to columns in excel with names and dates

Tags: excel

I wondered if anybody could help me out with a small problem. I am working on a big spreadsheet that contains names and the dates but i need to change a layout. To do this manually would take me an ages and I wondered if there is a quicker way.

This is what I have:

```
Column A              Column B       column C       
John Smith             start date1    end date1
John Smith             start date2    end date2
John Smith             start date3    end date3
Jane Doe               start date1    end date1
Jane Doe               start date2    end date2
Jane Doe               start date3    end date3
```

This is what i want is that all the start dates and the end dates are in one row, in separate columns against the name:

```
John Smith  start date1  end date1  start date2  end date2  start date2  end date2            
Jane Doe    start date1  end date1  start date2  end date2  start date2  end date2
```

In some cases I've got actually up to 5 start and end dates so the range will stretch further than 6 columns. Can any one help please?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe play around with a pivot table and see if you can get close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sort the table by alphabetical order on column A. Afterwards you can input this formula into the second row and bellow of a new column at the right of your current table.

```
=IF(A2=A1,CONCATENATE(D1,";",B2,";",C2),CONCATENATE("B2",";","C2")
```

For Cell D1 you can type the formula:

```
CONCATENATE("B1",";","C1")
```

This will create a string containing all the dates, which can then be divided into different rows using the Text to Columns function. However we still need to locate the complete string for each person in Column A, and for that we will need a new column E with the following formula:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,"Keep","Delete")
```

After consolidating the values in Column D by Copy Pasting and choosing the paste only values, you can filter the table for those rows with "Delete" on column E, and delete them.

After that's done, the only thing left should be to use the Text to Columns function using ";" as a separator.

That should do the trick.